# Concat function not giving desired result

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add dataframe to excel every time the code executes, in the last row available in the sheet. Here is the code I am using:

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def append_df_to_excel(df, excel_path):
    df_excel = pd.read_excel(excel_path)
    result = pd.concat([df_excel, df], ignore_index=True)
    result.to_excel(excel_path)

data_set1 = {
    'Name': ['Rohit', 'Mohit'],
    'Roll no': ['01', '02'],
    'maths': ['93', '63']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_set1)
append_df_to_excel(df1, r'C:\Users\kashk\OneDrive\Documents\ScreenStocks.xlsx')
```

My desired output(after 3 code runs):

```
Rohit   1   93
Mohit   2   63
Rohit   1   93
Mohit   2   63
Rohit   1   93
Mohit   2   63
```

But what I get:

```
    Unnamed: 0.1    Unnamed: 0  Name    Roll no maths
0       0                  0    Rohit   1       93
1       1                  1    Mohit   2       63
2       2                       Rohit   1       93
3       3                       Mohit   2       63
4                               Rohit   1       93
5                               Mohit   2       63
```

Not sure where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because in a default situation these functions like `to_excel` or `to_csv` (and etc.) add a new column with index. So every time you save the file, it adds a new column.
That's why you just should change the raw where you save your dataframe to a file.

```
result.to_excel(excel_path, index=False)
```